# What would be a better approach for a scalar function in C/C++ for Sqlite?

Tags: c++, sqlite

I've solid background as a C# programmer, but not experience with C/C++. Said that, I'm trying to create a scalar function to return an object, regardless the data type, through a void pointer as in bellow.

```
void * DB::Scalar(char * sqlCmd)
{   
sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sqlCmd, -1, &stmt, NULL);

void *obj = NULL;

if(sqlite3_step(stmt) == SQLITE_ROW)
{   
    if(sqlite3_column_type(stmt, 0) == SQLITE_INTEGER)
    {           
        int resInt = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0);
        obj = (void *)&resInt;

    }else if(sqlite3_column_type(stmt, 0) == SQLITE_TEXT)
    {   
                    //when column type is text copies string, so I can call
                    //sqlite3_finalize before return;

        char* tmp = (char* )sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0);
        int len = strlen(tmp) + 1;
        char* resChar = (char*)malloc(len);
        memset(resChar, 0, len);
        strcpy(resChar, tmp);

        obj = (void *)resChar;

    }else if(sqlite3_column_type(stmt, 0) == SQLITE_FLOAT)
    {   
        double resDoub = sqlite3_column_double(stmt, 0);
        obj = (void *)&resDoub;
    }

    sqlite3_finalize(stmt);

    return obj;//return void pointer and whoever calls it is responsible for
                       //the appropriate cast
}
}
```

That's look good?
I've tested and works pretty fine.

Comment: This is tagged with 3 different languages. It seems that only one is relevant (the language in which you are writing your solution). Please pick that one. (Pretty sure it's `C++`, in which case, stop trying to write it like `C`). Also, if you tested it and it works fine, why are you here?

Comment: 1 - The tags were suggested by stackoverflow, and, I think, its ok, as I using cpp for coding, the Sqlite API is pure C, the database engine is Sqlite and last but not least this is approach I've use in C#. 2 - Tons of codes were tested before and worked, but does not mean good software or well written.

Comment: Have you checked [`sqlite3_value`](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/value.html)? SQLite CAPI already provides an "interface" for dynamic typing. ([sqlite3_column_value](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/column_blob.html), ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since C++ does not contain type introspection capabilities in any real sense, you might want to use a template function (or a family of them) instead.  I would probably start by wrapping the `sqlite3_stmt` management in a resource class like:

```
class sqlite3_statement {
public:
    sqlite3_statement(sqlite3 *db, std::string const& query) {
        sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, query.c_str(), -1, &stmt_handle, NULL);
    }
    ~sqlite3_statement() {
        sqlite3_finalize(stmt_handle);
    }
    bool get_next_row() {
        return sqlite3_step(stmt_handle) == SQLITE_ROW;
    }
    int column_type(int index) {
        return sqlite3_column_type(stmt_handle, index);
    }
    operator sqlite3_stmt*() { return stmt_handle; }
private:
    sqlite3_stmt *stmt_handle;
};
```

That will make the resource management cleaner and safer via the RAII principle.  Then you can implement `query_for_scalar` as a family of template functions.  Note that you will need to explicitly specialize for each scalar type that you want to support.

```
template <typename T> T query_for_scalar(std::string const& query);

template <> int
query_for_scalar<int>(std::string const& query)
{
    sqlite3_statement statement(db, query);

    if (statement.get_next_row()) {
        if (statement.column_type(0) != SQLITE_INTEGER) {
            throw runtime_error("invalid column type");
        }
        return sqlite_column_int(statement, 0);
    } else {
        throw runtime_error("no row retrieved");
    }
}


template <> float
query_for_scalar<float>(std::string const& query)
{
    sqlite3_statement statement(db, query);

    if (statement.get_next_row()) {
        if (statement.column_type(0) != SQLITE_FLOAT) {
            throw runtime_error("invalid column type");
        }
        return sqlite_column_float(statement, 0);
    } else {
        throw runtime_error("no row retrieved");
    }
}
```

The type mapping could be done using a converter type as well.  It might be a little cleaner that way.  In either case, this will avoid the UB mentioned by other posters and it is a more C++ idiomatic solution.

Comment: I like that! Way more C# style! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

In this piece of code, you have undefined behavior:

```
if(sqlite3_column_type(stmt, 0) == SQLITE_INTEGER)
{           
    int resInt = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0);
    obj = (void *)&resInt;
}
```

The problem with is that the scope of the `resInt` variable is only inside that block between the `{` and the `}`. Once the code leaves that block that variable is no longer in scope, and any pointer to that variable is no longer valid.

Comment: If you take a closer look You'll notice &resInt cast to void *, as said before works fine.

Comment: @ramires.cabral just because it works doesn't mean it's fine. It's undefined behaviour; in practice the compiler might reuse that stack space for something else.

Comment: Thanks, that's my question. So, a better way to do that would be?

Comment: @ramires.cabral I haven't worked with SQLite much, but this is a function called by yourself from C++ and not some custom SQL function, right?

Comment: @ramires.cabral Possibly allocate and copy, similar to what you do to strings. This simplifies the handling of the returned pointer as you then can free it unconditionally without worrying if it's a string or not.

Comment: That's correct. In C# I've something close to that, mysql, sqlserver and sqlite have a Scalar method which return an object, and I just need to cast.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thanks, let me try that!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is nothing as C/C++ language. This does not mean, of course, that you cannot mix C and C++ constructs, or use C APIs from C++ (you can use C APIs from pretty much any decent language); however it does mean that whether the response should be C or C++ significantly affect the program.

What you have, at the moment, is a buggy C function with a quite unsafe interface. Since we are talking about C, unsafe is generally accepted, though we can do significantly better.

```
typedef enum { None, Int, CString } Kind_t;

typedef struct Result { Kind_t kind; void* item; } Result_t;

// Note: the memory pointed by Result_t::item, if any, falls
//       under the responsibility of the caller.
Result_t db_scalar(char const* sqlCmd) {
    // where do db and stmt come from ?
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sqlCmd, -1, &stmt, NULL);

    Result_t result = { None, 0 };

    if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_ROW) { goto exit; }

    if (sqlite3_column_type(stmt, 0) == SQLITE_INTEGER)
    {
        int* i = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
        if (i == 0) { goto exit; }

        *i = sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0);
        result = { Int, i };

        goto exit;
    }

    if (sqlite3_column_type(stmt, 0) == SQLITE_TEXT)
    {
        char const* tmp = (char*) sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0);
        if (tmp == 0) { goto exit; }

        size_t const len = strlen(tmp) + 1;

        char* text = (char*) malloc(len);
        if (text == 0) { goto exit; }

        strncpy(text, tmp, len);
        result = { CString, text };

        goto exit;
    }

exit:
    sqlite3_finalize(&stmt);
    return result;
} // db_scalar
```

I did a couple changes to your initial proposal:

- The result type now indicates the kind of the element, so the caller does not have to guess
- The caller is made responsible for the memory pointed to by `item`
- The statements are unnested, though we preserve the single exit point for cleanup purposes
- Various null checks in places where they can be expected

---

And what of C++ ? Well, things change in an interesting fashion.

```
// RAII class to always finalize a statement
class StatementFinalizer {
public:
    explicit StatementFinalizer(sqlite3_stmt& stmt): stmt(stmt) {}
    ~StatementFinalizer() { sqlite3_finalize(&stmt); }
private:
    sqlite3_stmt& stmt;
}; // class StatementFinalizer


using Result = boost::variant<boost::none_t, int, std::string>;

Result DB::scalar(std::string const& sqlCmd) {
    sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sqlCmd.c_str(), -1, &stmt, nullptr);
    StatementFinalizer const deferred(stmt);

    if (sqlite3_step(stmt) != SQLITE_ROW) { return boost::none; }

    if (sqlite3_column_type(stmt, 0) == SQLITE_INTEGER) {
        return sqlite3_column_int(stmt, 0);
    }

    if (sqlite3_column_type(stmt, 0) == SQLITE_TEXT) {
        unsigned char const* text = sqlite3_column_text(stmt, 0);
        return text ? std::string(text) : std::string("");
    }

    return boost::none;
} // DB::scalar
```

As you may note the C++ solution is significantly shorter. It is also more efficient (allocation-free for `int` for example).

On the other hand, its structure is basically identical, we just sidestep the Single Exit issue by using the power of destructors to always execute an action on exit.

Comment: Thanks! I just did something very close to your C approach. Indeed, C++ has a more elegant way to achieve same goal.